# Speed up data reading in pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, training-data

I am currently training a GAN model using two datasets with png images shaped 1040x1920 using pytorch. I am using this dataloader to load the images during training:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms 
from torchvision.transforms import functional as F 
from PIL import Image

class TrainImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path_real, path_fake, img_size=256):
        super(TrainImageDataset, self).__init__()

        self.real_images= [os.path.join(path_real, x) for x in os.listdir(path_real)]
        self.fake_images = [os.path.join(path_fake, x) for x in os.listdir(path_fake)]

        self.downscale = transforms.RandomCrop(img_size)
        self.hflip = transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)

    def __getitem__(self, batch_index):
        # Load the images
        real= Image.open(self.real_images[batch_index])
        fake = Image.open(self.fake_images[batch_index])

        # Apply augmentation functions
        fake = self.downscale(fake)
        real = self.downscale(real)
        fake = self.hflip(fake)
        real = self.hflip(real)

        # Convert the images to torch tensors
        real = F.to_tensor(real)
        fake = F.to_tensor(fake)
        return {'fake':fake , 'real':real}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.fake_images)
```

When training, I then pass the dataset into a DataLoader setting batch_size=8, num_workers=4, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, drop_last=True.

At the moment, I started using a much lighter model, and due to this the GPU Utilisation went from fixed 100% to averaging 27%, as I assume reading from disk probably takes longer than a training iteration. I have tried to move the augmentations to GPU but it's not convenient as the program now needs to load the entire 1040x1920 image to the GPU instead of the 256x256 crop.

Are there any alternatives I could use to speed up the data loading?

Comment: have you tried extracting multiple images in your `getitem` function? Meaning instead of taking only the image that correspond to `batch_index`, extract more. It will increase overall batch size but will call  `getitem` less, and if everything is vectorized it might not make a different algorithmic-wise

Comment: I did not think about that. It's a good idea, I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: In general this seems to be a recurring pain-point for pytorch users. Theoretically the `dataloader` class with multiple workers pre-caches data so that the loading is fast, but in practice loading seems to pin the speed down a lot of the time. You could easily build your own loader where it keeps a buffer of data full, but then you'd have to abandon pytorch's `dataloader` which for most people seems not worth it. Or try moving the loader itself off the main process

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check whether it is a disk reading problem, is to replace image load with fixed numpy array. Then you will clearly see if the data loading is bottleneck. Then you can do the same for augmentations and other data processing technics by turning them off. [Pyrotch profiler](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html) could help here.

If it's data loading problem, there are several ways to fix it, such as multithread loading (num_workers argument), data caching, use of different libraries, saving of preprocessed labels or images. You can find some of these ideas explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61393613/pytorch-speed-up-data-loading).

Also, be careful with pin_memory, since it [could lead to the CPU problems](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-disadvantage-of-using-pin-memory/1702/2?u=dinarkino) depending on details of your data and hardware. It's better to start with pin_memory=False.